# Solr search multiple word in query

Tags: php, search, solr

I have following fields in solr schema

```
make
model
city
province
```

I created a copyfield search and copy these 4 field in it

now I want, if a user is searching for

```
'audi a4' where audi is a make and a4 is model,
```

I should get result where in a row make is audi and model is a4.

In case if I search for

```
'asd audi asd'
```

then i should get result of audi only.

In case if i search for

```
'asd aasd audi asd a4',
```

then it should display audi a4 results.

Please help me to achieve this.

Please see schema for copy field

```
   <copyField source="Make" dest="search"/>
   <copyField source="Model" dest="search"/>
   <copyField source="City" dest="search"/>
```

Field created is as follow

```
<field name="search" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: whats the field type you are using?

Comment: I am using search as string

Comment: Can you share your schema?

Comment: Please see that edits

Comment: Change it to text_general and index and then try searching

Answer (score 0):

You can try this fieldType for your field.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

or you can try this field Type for search field

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

So your field is now

```
<field name="search" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: this is not working search:"audi a4" is giving result of only "audi"

Comment: Did your tried analysing the same in solr web interface tool?

Comment: what did you find? Can share the screenshot of it ...So that I can try at my end...

Comment: The solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory filter splits the word (token) into sub words. So the token "a4" will be split into two token "a" and "4". You are not doing the same in query phase of the analysis. I think solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory is not required given your requirement in the post. The 'text' fieldType suggested by @Abhijit should work. Also, the index and query phase are doing the same, so need not to specify them twice. Just specify the analyzer once without any type.

Comment: @abhishekbafna : preserveOriginal="1" would keep a4 as in the index. But yes it with op which one is suitable to him as per his requirement. In the text field type: yes i agree abhishek that its does not need to specify twice.