# Solr multiple word search

Tags: search, solr

I would like to know how can search row by adding multiple word in search.

i.e text is

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want to search

```
quick dog
```

so that I can get this row in result

if i search

quick elephant

still i should get this row in result.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

if i search brown i should get both row in result
if i search quick brown i should get only first line

Is this achievable with solr?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr search multiple word in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915451/solr-search-multiple-word-in-query)

Comment: @Pankaj, how far you have done research on this..? Have you defined schema file and indexed sample doc and verified the same? If not use the standard installation and index some data and verify, use text type for your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tune the way Solr matches multiple terms by using the `mm` parameter in the edismax query parser (as well as in the dismax query parser). While the second example (where the second line should be excluded), the `mm` parameter allows you to adjust exactly how many terms needs to be matched for a document to be considered valid for the search.

The second row will be scored lower than the first row in the second example, but you won't be able to exclude it.

Comment: Thanks Mats. Now I understand, even google not show result like this. Now I am concentrating on showing maximum match result first. 

"The second row will be scored lower than the first row in the second example, but you won't be able to exclude it."

So Now if I want to search Audi A5

I would like to display result with both word initially and then only audi or a5

Comment: @PankajS That will be the default behavior of Solr, as more matched terms will be scored higher than the single match. Unless you sort by some other criteria. Use debugQuery to see how the individual clauses affect your query result.

Answer (score -1):

Dear you can use AND operator (&&) between both work you wanat to search in a single document .
Like : **"quick" AND  "brown"** will give yoy one first document .
The AND operator matches documents where both terms exist anywhere in the text of a single document

Also prefer use of + sign stand for compulsion of word in documengt .

**+brown +quick**

The "+" or required operator requires that the term after the "+" symbol exist somewhere in a the field of a single document.

Ref : https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html